# CakePHP Star Rating

Tags: cakephp, rating, cakephp-2.2, rating-system

I am looking to implement a 5 star rating using jQuery Ajax in CakePHP. I came across a few plugins but they seem to be for 1.x version only.

Has any one implemented the same in the 2.2 version of CakePHP

Older versions:

http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/infest696/2011/05/21/star_rating_helper_with_jquery

http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/schneimi/2010/08/19/ajax-star-rating-plugin-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/cakedc/ratings

The documentation (readme.md) has everything you need. I just implemented it in one of my personal projects im working on - with AJAX - and it is easy to set up and works fine.

Comment: okay let me read thru and get back to you if i find it hard :D